# how to use map function when there are no records Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working with Reactjs,I am using Nextjs,Right now i am using component where i am
getting/fetch data using "axios",Problem is whenever i am get empty records( zero record in database) then i am getting following error
"this.state.trending.map is not a function"
Here is my current component code

```
import Link from "next/link";
import Moment from 'moment';
class Pin extends React.Component {
    state = {
        trending: []
      }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://diggdevelopment.com/blackstallion_new/api/pin',
        )
          .then(res => {
            const trending = res.data;
            this.setState({ trending });
          })
      }

    render() {

      return (
                <>
                   {this.state.trending.map((post, index) => {
                            //...further code...
                   }
            )
```

Comment: check `res.data`, if `res.data` is empty (`null` or `undefined`), assign empty array to `trending` so you won't get that error any more.

Comment: ... eg `const trending = res.data ?? [];`

Comment: Check the response if it's an array Array.isArray(res.data) and only set the state if it is true

Comment: @Phil can you please update my question so i can check and implement at my side

Comment: @Phil where should i use this line ? please explain

Comment: Where you currently have `const trending = res.data;`, replace it with `const trending = Array.isArray(res.data) ? res.data : [];`